# Does the call of join in the following CompletableFuture example block the process

Tags: java, nonblocking, completable-future

I am trying to understand CompletableFutures and chaining of calls that return completed futures and I have created the below example which kind of simulates two calls to a database.

The first method is supposed to be giving a completable future with a list of userIds and then I need to make a call to another method providing a userId to get the user (a string in this case).

to summarise:

1. fetch the ids
2. fetch a list of the users corresponding to those ids.

I created simple methods to simulate the responses with sleep threads.
Please check the code below

```java
public class PipelineOfTasksExample {

    private Map<Long, String> db = new HashMap<>();

    PipelineOfTasksExample() {
        db.put(1L, "user1");
        db.put(2L, "user2");
        db.put(3L, "user3");
        db.put(4L, "user4");
    }


    private CompletableFuture<List<Long>> returnUserIdsFromDb() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("building the list of Ids" + " - thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L));
    }

    private CompletableFuture<String> fetchById(Long id) {
        CompletableFuture<String> cfId = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> db.get(id));
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("fetching id: " + id + " -> " + db.get(id) + " thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return cfId;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PipelineOfTasksExample example = new PipelineOfTasksExample();

        CompletableFuture<List<String>> result = example.returnUserIdsFromDb()
                .thenCompose(listOfIds ->
                        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
                                () -> listOfIds.parallelStream()
                                        .map(id -> example.fetchById(id).join())
                                        .collect(Collectors.toList()
                                        )
                        )
                );

        System.out.println(result.join());
    }

}
```

My question is, does the join call (`example.fetchById(id).join()`) ruin the nonblocking nature of the process? If the answer is positive how can I solve this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your example is a bit odd as you are slowing down the main thread in `returnUserIdsFromDb()`, before any operation even starts and likewise, `fetchById` slows down the caller rather than the asynchronous operation, which defeats the entire purpose of asynchronous operations.

Further, instead of `.thenCompose(listOfIds -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> …))` you can simply use `.thenApplyAsync(listOfIds -> …)`.

So a better example might be

```
public class PipelineOfTasksExample {
    private final Map<Long, String> db = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(id -> id, id -> "user"+id));

    PipelineOfTasksExample() {}

    private static <T> T slowDown(String op, T result) {
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(500));
        System.out.println(op + " -> " + result + " thread: "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ ", "
            + POOL.getPoolSize() + " threads");
        return result;
    }
    private CompletableFuture<List<Long>> returnUserIdsFromDb() {
        System.out.println("trigger building the list of Ids - thread: "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> slowDown("building the list of Ids", Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)),
            POOL);
    }
    private CompletableFuture<String> fetchById(Long id) {
        System.out.println("trigger fetching id: " + id + " thread: "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> slowDown("fetching id: " + id , db.get(id)), POOL);
    }

    static ForkJoinPool POOL = new ForkJoinPool(2);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PipelineOfTasksExample example = new PipelineOfTasksExample();
        CompletableFuture<List<String>> result = example.returnUserIdsFromDb()
            .thenApplyAsync(listOfIds ->
                listOfIds.parallelStream()
                    .map(id -> example.fetchById(id).join())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()
                ),
                POOL
            );
        System.out.println(result.join());
    }
}
```

which prints something like

```
trigger building the list of Ids - thread: main
building the list of Ids -> [1, 2, 3, 4] thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1, 1 threads
trigger fetching id: 2 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0
trigger fetching id: 3 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
trigger fetching id: 4 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2
fetching id: 4 -> user4 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3, 4 threads
fetching id: 2 -> user2 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3, 4 threads
fetching id: 3 -> user3 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2, 4 threads
trigger fetching id: 1 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-3
fetching id: 1 -> user1 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2, 4 threads
[user1, user2, user3, user4]
```

which might be a surprising number of threads on the first glance.

The answer is that `join()` may block the thread, but if this happens inside a worker thread of a Fork/Join pool, this situation will be detected and a new compensation thread will be started, to ensure the configured target parallelism.

As a special case, when the default Fork/Join pool is used, the implementation may pick up new pending tasks within the `join()` method, to ensure progress within the same thread.

So the code will always make progress and there’s nothing wrong with calling `join()` occasionally, if the alternatives are much more complicated, but there’s some danger of too much resource consumption, if used excessively. After all, the reason to use thread pools, is to limit the number of threads.

The alternative is to use chained dependent operations where possible.

```
public class PipelineOfTasksExample {
    private final Map<Long, String> db = LongStream.rangeClosed(1, 4).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(id -> id, id -> "user"+id));

    PipelineOfTasksExample() {}

    private static <T> T slowDown(String op, T result) {
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toNanos(500));
        System.out.println(op + " -> " + result + " thread: "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName()+ ", "
            + POOL.getPoolSize() + " threads");
        return result;
    }
    private CompletableFuture<List<Long>> returnUserIdsFromDb() {
        System.out.println("trigger building the list of Ids - thread: "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> slowDown("building the list of Ids", Arrays.asList(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L)),
            POOL);
    }
    private CompletableFuture<String> fetchById(Long id) {
        System.out.println("trigger fetching id: " + id + " thread: "
            + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> slowDown("fetching id: " + id , db.get(id)), POOL);
    }

    static ForkJoinPool POOL = new ForkJoinPool(2);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PipelineOfTasksExample example = new PipelineOfTasksExample();

        CompletableFuture<List<String>> result = example.returnUserIdsFromDb()
            .thenComposeAsync(listOfIds -> {
                List<CompletableFuture<String>> jobs = listOfIds.parallelStream()
                    .map(id -> example.fetchById(id))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                return CompletableFuture.allOf(jobs.toArray(new CompletableFuture<?>[0]))
                    .thenApply(_void -> jobs.stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList()));
                },
                POOL
            );

        System.out.println(result.join());
        System.out.println(ForkJoinPool.commonPool().getPoolSize());
    }
}
```

The difference is that first, all asynchronous jobs are submitted, then, a dependent action calling `join` on them is scheduled, to be executed only when all jobs have completed, so these `join` invocations will never block. Only the final `join` call at the end of the `main` method may block the main thread.

So this prints something like

```
trigger building the list of Ids - thread: main
building the list of Ids -> [1, 2, 3, 4] thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1, 1 threads
trigger fetching id: 3 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
trigger fetching id: 2 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0
trigger fetching id: 4 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1
trigger fetching id: 1 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0
fetching id: 4 -> user4 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1, 2 threads
fetching id: 3 -> user3 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0, 2 threads
fetching id: 2 -> user2 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1, 2 threads
fetching id: 1 -> user1 thread: ForkJoinPool-1-worker-0, 2 threads
[user1, user2, user3, user4]
```

showing that no compensation threads had to be created, so the number of threads matches the configured target parallelism.

Note that if the actual work is done in a background thread rather than within the `fetchById` method itself, you now don’t need a parallel stream anymore, as there is no blocking `join()` call. For such scenarios, just using `stream()` will usually result in a higher performance.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for taking the time to reply. That was really helpful

Comment: Great example. I'm not sure to understand the difference between thenApplyAsync and thenComposeAsync. They both return a CompletableFuture. Not sure I get the intricacy with the stages.

Comment: @UltimaWeapon it’s the same difference as between `map` and `flatMap` in case of `Stream` or `Optional`. The method `thenApplyAsync` expects a function evaluating to a new value, whereas `thenComposeAsync` expects a function evaluating to a new stage which represent (or evaluates to) the new value. The latter is way more flexible, but unnecessary for trivial cases. Just like you wouldn’t write `.flatMap(x -> Stream.of(y))` for a stream when you can simply write `.map(x -> y)`

Comment: Does that mean that if i use join() on a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor there could be an issue with a deadlock scenario when my threadpool is already full? As join() may block? Scenario here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77537145/thread-pool-stops-accepting-tasks

Comment: @ThomasLang when you use `join()` in a worker thread of a limited thread pool (other than `ForkJoinPool`) you can indeed bring it to a complete halt. In other words, using `join()` with other executors is even more dangerous than using it with the `ForkJoinPool`. The solution would be to use virtual threads but I suppose, like most of us, you don’t have the possibility to use Java 21 in production code yet…

Comment: @Holger Thank you! So solutions to this problem would be the following: 1. Get rid of calling join() or 2. move the number of available Threads in the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor up, or 3. use a ForkJoinPool as ThreadPoolTaskExecutor? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it’s even the default; when you don’t specify an executor the [common pool](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool()) will be used. But you can also specify your own `ForkJoinPool` as executor.

Comment: @Holger Thank you. One last question: So defining/using your own Executor in a current Spring Boot 3 Environment is a) performing worse than the automatic configured common pool and b) there might be thread starvation if it is misconfigured?

Comment: @ThomasLang a) only if your own executor is not an instance of `ForkJoinPool` and you’re using lots of `join()` or `get()` calls. But keep in mind that this is nothing special; the behavior is similar to any scenario of making a lot of blocking calls in a thread pool. The actual difference is that there is a work-around in case of blocking calls on a `CompletableFuture` in a worker thread of a `ForkJoinPool` b) as said, it’s a general issue that making a lot of blocking calls in a thread pool can lead to starvation.